# Why does PGF require the designer of a new arrow tip kind to explicitly specify the arrow tip's convex hull?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

According to the 'Defining New Arrow Tip Kinds' chapter of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a (p. 1016), one of the parameters that must be specified every time a new arrow tip kind is defined is *convex hull*.

The convex hull of a shape is conceptually similar to its bounding box (but the two are not quite the same). As an illustration of the concept of a convex hull, consider the following picture of an arrow tip in design. The convex hull of the arrow tip is the triangle, whose vertices are (1,0), (-3,2), and (-3,-2).

[image: An arrow tip.]

One may wonder why the convex hull needs to be explicitly specified by the designer of the arrow tip kind, when PGF has a built-in mechanism for calculating bounding boxes. The manual addresses this question as follows (last bullet point in section 100.2 on p. 1016).

> Normally, `PGF` automatically keeps track of a bounding box of everything you draw. However, since arrow tips are drawn so often, `PGF` caches the code needing for drawing arrow tips internally and because of this cache it cannot determine the size of the arrow tip just based on the drawing commands used for drawing the tip. Instead, a convex hull of the arrow tip must be explicitly provided in the definition.

Why does the caching of the code needed for drawing the arrow tips preclude PGF from calculating the arrow tip's bounding-box without the user's hints?

Comment: I interpret the quotation as: PGF updates the picture's bounding box when performing a drawing command; however, drawing the arrow tips doesn't update the bounding box using the actual drawing commands, but just using the convex hull information stored at definition time. The convex hull can be more efficiently rotated or deformed according to the commands for drawing the arrow.

Comment: @egreg: But why can't PGF calculate the convex hull (alternatively, ,the bounding box) on its own just before caching?

Comment: Because arrow paths are protocoled (again a section in the manual) and the context is not discoverable. Also you might want to leave out certain parts if the arrow is too decorative such as Arc Barb which is a semi cirle (hooks is worse) and the convex hull is itself instead you provide an approximation of your choice. In summary, this is a design choice.

Comment: @percusse: Could you please make the explanation easier? What does it mean that the paths are 'protocoled'? What paths? What do you mean by 'contex'? By whom is it not discoverable? But above all: why is it *mandatory* to specify a convex hull? Why can't PGF deduce it on its own, at least by default?

Comment: @EvanAad You are the one who is jumping into the lowest levels of PGF and asking simple answers :) Imagine I give you a Bezier curve and ask you what the convex hull is, how do you find it ?

Comment: @percusse: I let PGF find the bounding box for me and call it good enough.

Comment: @EvanAad Yes but how? Here is an example to play with `\draw (0,0) ..controls (3,-4) and (-1,3) .. (1,1);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62501/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-percusse).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[image]

The red box is the official bounding box.

The green box is the bounding box of the arrowhead.

The blue box is the fictional bounding box that is calculated using the green box instead of the convex hull.

---

Playing code

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\foreach\i in{1,...,60}{
    \tikz[line width=.1cm]{
        \draw[rotate=\i*6,line width=1cm,-{>[length=3cm]}](0,0)--(7,0);
        \draw[red](current bounding box.south west)rectangle(current bounding box.north east);
        \pgfinterruptboundingbox
            \draw[line width=1cm,-{>[length=3cm]},transparent](6,0)--(7,0);
            \path(current bounding box.south west)coordinate(A)
                 (current bounding box.south east)coordinate(B)
                 (current bounding box.north west)coordinate(C)
                 (current bounding box.north east)coordinate(D);
            \draw[green,transform canvas={rotate=\i*6}](A)rectangle(D);
        \endpgfinterruptboundingbox
        \path([rotate=\i*6]A)([rotate=\i*6]B)([rotate=\i*6]C)([rotate=\i*6]D);
        \draw[blue](current bounding box.south west)rectangle(current bounding box.north east);
        \path(-10,-10)(10,10);
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorcery! Off with his head!

Comment: Very cool! Is the animation effect achieved solely with TikZ?

Comment: @EvanAad With the help of ImageMagick, you can convert a series of PDF pages into a GIF file. The terminal command used here is `convert -delay 10 -dispose previous -density 100 381452.pdf 52.gif`.

Comment: Thanks. Your code produces 60 pdf pages, but I don't see any `\newpage` command. How does TikZ know to jump to the next page?

Comment: It is the `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` that will separate each `tikzpicture` into individual pages. By the way, `\tikz` is an alternative of the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that an arrow tip's bounding box is the bounding box of its explicitly specified convex hull?

Comment: @EvanAad Well... here is the tricky point: the arrowhead's bounding box (no matter what it is) is unrelated to the overall bound box calculation. Ti*k*Z instead shifts and rotates the convex hull's coordinates directly and calculate the overall bounding box. (It is pointless to *pre-calculate/cache* an arrowhead bounding box because every time you rotate the arrowhead the bounding box changes.)

Comment: @EvanAad Correct. But what are you going to do with this information? I mean... it is hopeless that there is a node called `(current arrowhead bounding box)`...

Comment: A magnificent answer, and I don't even use `tikz`.  Bravo!